# Extension of Bernstein’s Inequality when the random variable is bounded with large probability

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration

Bernstein’s Inequality can be stated as follows : Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be independent bounded random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[x_i] = 0$ and $|x_i| \leq \zeta$ with probability $1$ and let $\sigma^2 = \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n} Var\{x_i\}$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq \epsilon \right] \leq \exp{\left\{ \frac{-n \epsilon^2}{ 2 \sigma^2 + 2\zeta \epsilon/3} \right\}}
$$

If instead of $|x_i| \leq \zeta$ with probability $1$, it is the case that $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\left\{ |x_i| > \zeta \right\} \leq \delta$, then is the following applicable?

$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq \epsilon \right] \leq \exp{\left\{ \frac{-n \epsilon^2}{ 2 \sigma^2 + 2\zeta \epsilon/3} \right\}} + \delta     \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)
$$

I think, the above extension is similar to the extension of the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality proved in Theorem 32 of [Chung and Lu(2006)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1175266369). The question concerning the extension of the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality was also asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171479/extension-of-the-azuma-hoeffding-inequality-when-the-differences-are-bounded-wi).

Is it possible to extend Bernstein’s Inequality as eq. $(1)$ following the lines of the proof of Theorem 32 in [Chung and Lu(2006)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1175266369)?

Addendum : The Freedman inequality for martingales is a result like the Bernstein inequality but where the random variables can be dependent. Is an extension like the above possible for Freedman inequality?

For reference Freedman inequality (Theorem 1.6 in [Freedman (1975)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996452)] ) can be stated as follows: let $x_1, x_2, \dots $ be a martingale difference sequence and $|x_i| \leq \zeta$ for all $i$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq \epsilon, \sum_{i=1}^{n} var(x_i | \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) \leq \eta \right] \leq \exp{\left\{ \frac{-\epsilon^2}{2\eta + 2 \zeta \epsilon/3 } \right\}}.
$$

If instead of $|x_i| \leq \zeta$ with probability $1$, it is the case that $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\left\{ |x_i| > \zeta \right\} \leq \delta$, then is the following applicable?
$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq \epsilon, \sum_{i=1}^{n} var(x_i | \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) \leq \eta \right] \leq \exp{\left\{ \frac{-\epsilon^2}{2\eta + 2 \zeta \epsilon/3 } \right\}} + \delta \qquad  \qquad (2)
$$
Thank you.

Comment: For $\delta=1$, it looks like your eq. (1) doesn't recover Bernstein's inequality -- is there maybe a typo somewhere?

Comment: @gmvh It, obviously, should be $1-\delta$ in the assumption but I agree that it would be nice to fix it.

Comment: By "$|x_i| \leq \zeta$ with probability $\delta$", do you mean "$P(\max_i|x_i| \leq \zeta)=1-\delta$ or "$P(|x_i| \leq \zeta)=1-\delta$ for all $i$" or ...?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo @fedja.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thanks. I have clarified it now.

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity resolved. Which one of the first two versions I listed do you have in mind?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I have made it more explicit. Please let me know if it's unambiguous now. I was also wondering if Bernstein inequality could work with different upper bounds on $|x_i|$  i.e $|x_i| \leq \zeta_i $ instead of $|x_i| \leq \zeta $. But I see you have already answered that it's not possible [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/291942/165018).

Comment: @Komkom : Also, you are citing Freedman's Theorem 1.6 incorrectly: instead of $x_i^2$, you need $Var(x_i|\mathcal F_{i-1})$.

Comment: Doesn't your (1) follow from using Freedman (the correct version, as Iosif Pinelis points out) instead of Azuma in the Chung-Lu argument, and noting $\delta$ is an upper bound (union) for $Pr(B)$ in their paper?

As a cheap justification, note that you can couple $x_i$ to $y_i$ defined to be equal to $x_i$ if $|x_i|\le\zeta$ and $0$ otherwise. If the $y_i$ have mean zero, then they are by Bernstein concentrated as you desire, and the failure probability of the coupling is at most $\delta$, so you get (1).

Comment: Of course, in general the $y_i$ will not have mean zero, so they concentrate to whatever the sum of their expectations actually is. This can only be a problem if the sum of expectations is far from zero. But for that to happen, the $x_i$ have to have a significant contribution to expectation from when they come out bigger than $\zeta$ (or smaller, in the other direction). That blows up the variance of the $x_i$ (compared to that of the $y_i$); the $y_i$ will be more concentrated when you use the correct variance. So... if you want to know if (1) will go wrong,

Comment: then the following random variables are what you should look at. Take $\zeta=1$ (this just sets the scale), and each $x_i$ to be $-t$ with probability $1/(t+1)$, and otherwise $1$. And suppose you have $n$ variables. Then we have to take $\delta=n/(t+1)$, so for there to be any way for (1) to fail, we need $n<t+1$. Since the sum of the $x_i$ is likely to be about $1$, we should take $\varepsilon<1$, and (it's easy to check) say $0.99$ is about as good as we can do.
Now we can write out the LHS of (1) explicitly - the probability is the same as that some $x_i$ comes out to $-t$

Comment: and the right hand side is easy enough to figure out. Using Taylor to expand the exponential, you (just!) get enough cancellation between $\delta$ and the negative exponential that (1) is true for these particular random variables.

Comment: @user36212, Thanks for your comments. Using the same argument as in the Chung-Lu paper (pr(B) for union probability of bad event), could (2) be proved as well? For my purpose (2) is more relevant as the random variables (r.v.'s) are dependent rather than independent.

Comment: Wrt my previous previous comment, $B$ is the bad set associated with the following : $|x_i| \leq \zeta$ and $var(x_i | \mathcal{F_{i-1}}) \leq \sigma_i^2$. And in (2), $\eta = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Your inequality (2) does hold. Actually, a better and more general bound holds. First here, let us standardize and simplify notations. Let us use $X_i$ instead of $x_i$, $x$ instead of $\epsilon$, $y>0$ instead of $\zeta$, $B^2>0$ instead of $\eta$, $Var_{i-1}\,\cdot$ instead of $var(\cdot|\mathcal{F}_{i-1})$, and $E_{i-1}\,\cdot$ instead of $E(\cdot|\mathcal{F}_{i-1})$.

Instead of the conditions that the $x_i$'s are martingale differences and $\sum_{i=1}^n P(|x_i|>\zeta)\le\de$, let us use the more general conditions that the $X_i$'s are supermartingale differences and
\begin{equation}
    P(\max_{i=1}^n X_i>y)\le\de.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Let also $Y_i:=X_i\,1(X_i\le y)$ and $Z_i:=Y_i\,1(V_i\le B^2)=X_i\,1(X_i\le y,V_i\le B^2)$, where
$$V_i:=\sum_{j=1}^i E_{j-1}\,Y_j^2.$$
Note that $V_i$ is no greater than $\sum_{j=1}^i E_{j-1}\,X_j^2$, which latter coincides with $\sum_{j=1}^i Var_{j-1}\,X_j$ in the special case when the $X_i$'s are martingale differences.

By (1),
$$P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge x,V_n\le B^2\Big)\le P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\ge x,V_n\le B^2\Big)+\de.$$
Obviously, $V_i\le V_n$ for $i\le n$. So,
$$P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\ge x,V_n\le B^2\Big)\le P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\ge x\Big).$$

Next, $E_{i-1}Z_i=1(V_i\le B^2)E_{i-1}Y_i\le 1(V_i\le B^2)E_{i-1}X_i\le0$, so that the $Z_i$'s are supermartingale differences. Also, $E_{i-1}Z_i^2\le E_{i-1}X_i^2$. So, by [Theorem 8.2 on page 1702](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176988477), we have the Hoeffding-type inequality
\begin{equation*}
    P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\ge x\Big)\le\exp\Big\{\frac{B^2}{y^2}\psi\Big(\frac{xy}{B^2}\Big)\Big\},
\end{equation*}
where $\psi(u):=u-(1+u)\ln(1+u)$. Collecting the pieces, we get
\begin{equation*}
    P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge x,V_n\le B^2\Big)\le\exp\Big\{\frac{B^2}{y^2}\psi\Big(\frac{xy}{B^2}\Big)\Big\}+\de. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
The latter bound is better than the Bernstein-type bound
\begin{equation*}
    \exp\Big\{-\frac{x^2}{2B^2+2xy/3}\Big\}+\de, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
because, as shown in [Theorem 3](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1134032), the Hoeffding-type bound is the best exponential bound in its terms. Another, direct way to see that the bound in (2) is better than (3) is to use the inequality $\psi(u)\le-u^2/(2+2u/3)$ for real $u\ge0$.

Thus, the bound in (2) is better and more general than what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I read [Theorem 3](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1134032) but I don't understand how it shows that the obtained bound is the best exponential bound. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Komkom : The inequality sign in Theorem 3 (and in other results in that paper) is, not $\leqq$, but $\overset{(T)}\leqq$, which means that the bounds are exact (best possible), in the sense defined on the first page of that paper. The letter T is the first letter of the Russian word "точный", meaning "exact".